How to check whether a finite $p$-group is regular in GAP?
I am trying to check whether a given $p$-group is a regular $p$-group in GAP. I am trying to use the command 'IsRegularPGroup(G)' for it. However I am getting 'Error, Variable: 'IsRegularPGroup' must have a value'. Please help.
I am pasting the code which I am trying to implement in SAGE:
for n in [81]:
k=len(gap(n).AllSmallGroups())
for i in [1..k]:
    X = gap.Image(gap.IsomorphismPermGroup(gap.SmallGroup(n,i)))
    Z=PermutationGroup(gap_group = X)
    
    print(n,i,gap.StructureDescription(Z),gap.IsRegularPGroup(Z))


Which version of GAP are you using? The command IsRegularPGroup was added fairly recently it seems, 4.13.0 from March 2024.

I am using 14.2.2.

The command IsRegularPGroup was added into GAP in version 4.13.0 (March 2024), as mentioned here.
To fix your problem update to the latest version of GAP.
